# catch multiple parameters in htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have an URL `act/city/1/page.html` where city,1 are coming from database.
The htaccess rule I use is:

```
RewriteRule ^act/city/([^/]+)\.html$ page\.php?i=$1&p=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

If I print my REQUEST in php, it displays: `Array ( [id] => city/1 )` instead of 
`Array ( [id] => 1 )`.

Kindly assist

Comment: Show us your other rules! The REQUEST dump is the wrong one, there is no `id` parameter in your redirect!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. Also, the rule you have shown us is not the correct one for your URL.

My rule:

```
RewriteRule ^act/city/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ /page.php?i=$1&p=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Note that I added a slash before `page.php`.

My URL:

```
http://localhost/act/city/1/2.html
```

My result:

```
array(2) {
  ["i"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["p"]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code

```
RewriteRule ^act/city/([^/]+)\.html$ page.php?i=$1&p=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

There is no need to put Slash() after '$'.

Thanks.